# FontAwesome icons are appearing as squares, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use their CDN via the BootstrapCDN but that didn't work so I tried to register and get my own CDN but that doesn't work either, they both produce these squares instead of the icon.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/MY-PERSONAL-ONE.css">
```

[image]

Here is what the icons look like

Edit: I ended up using the public one their website after I clicked 'Want to use Font Awesome without Font Awesome CDN?' and it worked..

Heres where that linked to: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FontAwesome's CDN](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css) rather than Bootstrap's. I've actually had this exact issue previously with CDNs hosted by BootstrapCDN.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">`